# How to use in docker a mysql databases form /var/lib/mysql?

Tags: docker

I run my docker-compose.yml file and have a container with php CMS, php, apache, and other container with mysql server.

When I open the site from docker in browser I am prompted to install that CMS.
With volumes I replaced CMS files by files from /var/www/html/my_site, now I see its in docker container.

If I change CMS config file and write needed data to connect to db, I got problems.

How to use in docker a mysql database form local machine.
I think that is possible with volumes by connecting /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: You can’t use a single database directory with two server instances. So either your MySQL server is running on the host (you don’t need a DB container then) or you’ll use a container but not `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: I write to mariadb service `- ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql` and I think that in container I will see the databases from my host

Comment: No, you won’t. Why are you trying to use a container when you already have a database server?

Comment: I don't want to put my 6 GB database in container, I think I will see it like i see the CMS files from my host in container with `volumes:  - /var/www/html:/var/www/html`

Comment: Yes, you can map the directory. No, this won’t help. If you have a database server on the host, connect to it from the CMS. Directly. No other containers involved.

Comment: And I want to connect mariadb, apache containers with different versions